# Applying single XSLT on thousand XML Files present in a directory

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I had written an XSLT file to transform an XML file from unstructured form to more structured format. But problem is I am having thousands of XML files present in a directory/sub-directory structure and I want to apply same XSLT on all of them & generate new structured XML corresponding to them. I tried things using Collection() but did not worked. I am using Altova XMLSpy.

XML files Looks something like this:

```
<University xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 SchemaVersion="1.0.8">
 <UniName>StackOverflow</UniName>
 <UniId>123</UniId>
 <Courses>
  <Course>
   <ID>1001</ID>
   <Seats>10</Seats>
   <Description>Department: CS , Faculty: XYZ</Description>
  </Course>
  <Course>
   <ID>1001</ID>
   <Seats>10</Seats>
   <Description>To teach how to Write XSLT</Description>
  </Course>
  <Address>Planet No.# 3 Earth</Address>
  <ZipCode>007</ZipCode>
 </Courses>
</University>
```

Its Corresponding XSLT Files is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-
functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">
  <ConnectUni>
<xsl:for-each select="University">
  <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_first" as="node()" select="Courses"/>
     <Address>
        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string($var1_resultof_first/Address)"/>
     </Address>
         <Courses>
     <xsl:for-each select="$var1_resultof_first/Course">
        <Course>
      <Id>
                 <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(ID)"/>
      </Id>
      <Seats>
         <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(Seats)"/>
      </Seats>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Description"></xsl:apply-templates>
          </Course>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Courses> 
   </xsl:for-each>
 </ConnectUni>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Description">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Department:\s*(.+)\s*,\s*Faculty:\s*(.+)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:element name="Department"><xsl:value-of select="fn:string(regex-group(1))"/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="Faculty"><xsl:value-of select="fn:string(regex-group(2))"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:element name="Description"><xsl:value-of select="fn:string(.)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
   </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am looking for solution in Java or C# as I have to transform the newly generated XML files into a RDBMS from where SQL queries can be done.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it from Java then you could read the directory structure in Java and invoke transform() once for each file, assuming (as I understand it) each input file is transformed into an output file independently of any other files.

Alternatively, you could control it from within the XSLT. Assuming Saxon, you would add a template rule

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection(concat($directory, '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))">
    <xsl:result-document href="{......}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </
  </
</
```

and then start the transformation nominating "main" as the initial template, without supplying a source document.

Comment: Thank you Michael for replying. Can you share the code for java code for reading multiple XML files and invoking transform() for each of them and saving newly generated XML files at a different directory. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can find example code that does this in the module net.sf.saxon.Transform in the open source Saxon product.

Comment: Is there any solution just in java other than using SAXon processor as I had to mark the read files as being read by setting file attributes so that I am not end up reading same file again. Thank you in advance